# Ruby on rails form input error formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formbuilder

The default behavior for a regular rails form that has errors is to 1) list the errors in a div, with the text coming from `errors_for` and 2) to place a div around the offending inputs with a red border.  This question is concerning #2.

I'd like to know how rails goes about applying that div with the red border.

I'd like to know because I have some form inputs that aren't generated with `f.text_field` (for example), but they are attached to a model that can have errors.

I looked around in the source of `action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb`  All I was able to figure out is that form errors aren't applied by `form_tag_helper`

Answer (score 1):

The red border is added by ActionView::Base.field_error_proc

To change this behaviour:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#customizing-the-error-messages-html